# How to put INT into name of variable

Tags: java

So i have a lot of variables called really similar.

```
im1=...;
im2=...;//And so on
```

I need to be able to use .setText(); with it.
I also have a int that shows what variable do i need.
How can i make this stuff?

```
int number=2;
im<number>.setText();// I want to make this like im2.setText();
```

Comment: Why not use arrays? Or Lists? Or Maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming#Java) to do that. See [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/TOC.html) by Oracle Corp. But reflection is slow and error-prone, and should be used only as a last resort.

Better to use other data structures provided by Java.

## Array

An array gives you an sequence of objects. Access each element by way of an annoyingly zero-based index number.

```
String[] names = new String[ 3 ] ;

names[ 0 ] = "Alice" ;
names[ 1 ] = "Bob" ;
names[ 2 ] = "Carol" ;
```

If your variable `number` is one-based ordinal number, just subtract one to access array.

```
String name = names[ number - 1 ] ;
```

## `List`

`List` is similar to array, but much more flexible and helpful.

```
List< String > names = List.of( "Alice", "Bob", "Carol" ) ;
```

Retrieval in `List` also uses annoying zero-based index counting.

```
String name = names.get( number - 1 ) ;
```

## `NavigableSet`

If you want to collect objects in sorted order, use an implementation of the [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) interface. The Java platform includes two, `TreeSet` and `ConcurrentSkipListSet`. A set eliminates duplicates.

Third parties may also provide implementations. Perhaps in *Google Guava*, or *Eclipse Collections*.

## `Map`

And I suggest you learn about key-value pairs in a `Map`.

```
Map< Integer , String > numberedNames = 
    Map.of( 
        1 , "Alice" ,
        2 , "Bob" ,
        3 , "Carol" 
    )
;
```

Retrieval.

```
String name = numberedNames.get( number ) ;
```

The code shown here transparently uses auto-boxing to automatically convert from `int` primitive values to `Integer` objects.

---

See [*The Java™ Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) online provided free of cost by Oracle. They cover all three, arrays, `List`, and `Map`.